# Is it possible to sync iCloud data between different iCloud accounts?

Tags: ios, ipad, icloud, cloudkit

I'm building an i0S 8 iPad app for a friend's business to help him and his employees sync appraisal data between devices. In other words, if one employee creates an appraisal, that appraisal should be accessible by all other employees that are running the app. The appraisal data is composed of a few strings, a few numbers, and some image files.

I've built a few other iOS apps, but this is the first app I've built that deals with syncing data between devices. Since it's an iPad-only app, iCloud sounds like the ideal cloud service to use for the syncing functionality. The problem is, all the iPads are personal iPads and have different iCloud accounts.

1. Is there a way to sync app data between different iCloud accounts using CloudKit?
2. If not, do you have any other ideas for how I can sync this kind of data between iPads?

I'm still reading up on CloudKit, but I wanted to post this question in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

In CloudKit there is a private and a public database. when you write to the public database, then that data could be read by others. You could create subscriptions so that users would be notified if there are changes. Most of the security has to be handled inside your app. If you are worried about that, then you could use encryption (using private and public keys)